# How to get Python Azure Function App with Java

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I am trying to make a simple azure function app that uses tabula-py.  However, this package has a java dependency.  When I try to run it, I get an error about java not being in PATH.
I've tried to add java to the fileshare but I get the same error.

Whenever I use jdk, I get the error  `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/.jre/jdk-15.0.2+7-jre/lib/server/classes.jsa'`

Is there a way to get java and python running in the same function app?

Comment: Are these helpful? [Exception: JavaNotFoundError When Running Tabula-py in a python azure funciton app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61859943/exception-javanotfounderror-when-running-tabula-py-in-a-python-azure-funciton-a), [I am getting JAVA_HOME not set error on azure python webapp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66867154/i-am-getting-java-home-not-set-error-on-azure-python-webapp) and [Azure Function App with Multiple Runtimes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67290249/azure-function-app-with-multiple-runtimes)

Comment: Unfortunately not.  I've tried all of the solutions I could (without containerization) but nothing worked for me.  The last one got me the closest.

Answer (score 0):

Officially only one runtime is supported on Azure function where you specify language of your function app is maintained in the FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME as documented here: learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/… In case if any issue with your function app, then it may not be supported. I think function on Linux using a custom container would be the possible solution where you have full control.